# Can't compile mongodb c++ driver Linux Centos 5.6

Tags: c++, mongodb, compiler-errors, driver, x11

After installing the MongoDB, on the server-side, I attempted to configure my client which, resides on a CentOS 5.6 OS using the C++ driver code, from the link below:

http://dl.mongodb.org/dl/cxx-driver/

The install went well !  I worked through the tutorials with no problems but, at this point, I need to build this in with my group's build process.  When I attempt to compile, I receive the following error:

```
/usr/local/include/mongo/base/error_codes.h:36: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
/usr/local/include/mongo/base/error_codes.h:36: error: expected '}' before numeric constant

....
```

At this point, I said to myself there must be another #define that is colliding with this code.  So, I ran the `g++ ... -E` command and found that, in `/usr/include/X11/X.h`, there is a `#define BadValue`.

This seems weird to me because I would not expect this to happen if the code was enclosed in some namespace which `error_codes.h` is enclosed in the `mongo` namespace.  So, I searched my entire filesystem looking for something like `using namespace mongo` thinking that the global namespace was polluted but, this is not the case.  I do not see any instances of this occurring and I am wondering - because both of these are third-party - how to resolve.

Thoughts?

Comment: macros do not honor namespaces.

Comment: error_codes.h defines "BadValue" within an enum not a #define.  Does your comment still apply ?  Thanks.

Comment: of course it does. macros are only little more than textual replacements. have a look at the preprocessed code.